# Find last file access in python

Tags: python

I am trying to get the last access file using Python. Even after accessing the files using vi/sublime or any other editor, the access time of the file does not get updated.
I have tried to use the function `os.stat(full_path).st_atime` but of no use. It throws out the correct result only if the file is modified.

Just following up on the link [alternative to getatime to find last file access in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23746565/alternative-to-getatime-to-find-last-file-access-in-python)

Comment: `atime` needs filesystem support to work. it seems like yours does not

Comment: On what OS are you working?

Comment: I am working on Linux (Ubuntu). I was able to find the solution using find command in Linux: find /home/dir/ -atime -10 -print. But, I want use this command using Python. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

You should check this way:

```
(mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime) = os.stat(file)
print "last access: %s" % time.ctime(atime)
```

I recommend you to check official info at [`os.stat()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat):

*To check **creation&modification** dates*

```
print "last modified: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file))
print "created: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getctime(file))
```

**OR**

```
(mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime) = os.stat(file)
print "Modification date: %s" % time.ctime(mtime)
print "Creation date: %s" % time.ctime(ctime)
```

Comment: Thanks Liarez for answering this, but still when I access the file recently, the atime parameter does not get updated and reveals the old timestamp.The os.stat() documentation reveals that st_atime has only 1-day resolution. What does it mean?

Comment: How are you accessing the file ?

Comment: Using vi <filename> or subl <filename>.

Comment: Not all the commands modify the access tiem of a file. If you want to change the access time of a file you can use `touch -a filename` and then if you check the `atime` it will be updated. I'm not sure why **vi** isn't modifying the atime

Comment: Maybe this question could be useful to you: [Access time does not change after a file is opened](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551139/access-time-does-not-change-after-a-file-is-opened)

Comment: And also this question may help you to understand why is this happening, and why the atime is not being updated: [Why is not changing the access time?](http://superuser.com/a/464737)

Comment: Thank you so much Liarez. You've been of awesome help. I have relatime default mount option on my OS. Need to change it and try.

Comment: Take care with this kind of changes ! I'm happy my answer helped you

Answer (score 0):

Find last creation file:

```
def findlatestfile(folder):
    list_of_files = glob.glob(folder+'/*') 
    latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
    return latest_file
```